# SQL Job failure The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password

Tags: sql

the scheduled SQL job failed and it gave the first error message:

```
"Cannot create object XXIRegistry.MachineRegistry"
```

and while running it manually it runs successfully and after retrieving the HResult, I found 2 errors as below.

```
Note:XXIRegistry is a library registered on the database server 
1- 0x800407D1 86,XXIRegistryStore.RegistryStore Trying to create: XXIRegistryStore.RegistryStore
2- 0x8000401A The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.
```

we have 2 nodes of the database servers (clustered database)

Comment: Did you check the user name and password? You have provided no background about this problem only the error report. Which means the only advice I can give is go and check the username and password.

Comment: i already solved it by adding a new com+application and added a group and enrolled the user to that group